# Gray lines instead of camera feed in ARCore app builds

Tags: arcore

When I build and run the "Hello Sceneform" and "Solar System" projects that I downloaded while following the Android Quickstart  https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart, all I see on my phone (a Galaxy S9) are   [these shifting gray/black lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrTtx.jpg), with the moving ARCore hand/phone on top.

I can download and run ARCore apps from the store without a hitch. The S9 is the only ARCore-compatible phone I can test with. I'm using Android Studio 3.2 preview, Windows 10, ARCore 1.2, and Android 8.0.0.

When I try running on any emulator device, it immediately crashes before displaying anything, which is likely due to the fact that I don't think my desktop GPU supports OpenGL ES 3.1, based on the output when I run "adb logcat | grep eglMakeCurrent". Right now  my goal is just to get it working on my phone, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  In the future issues like this are better reported via a GitHub issue: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues

Comment: I am running on nexus5x Android 8.1, works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The grey bars for the Galaxy S9 is a bug (see: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/28).

As of July 18th it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try using the NDK Quickstart instructions instead, found [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/quickstart).

After a few installations and updates of Gradle, etc.

running /samples/hello_ar_c via USB to an S9
worked flawlessy. Hope this helps.