# Nothing but grey bars when loading Sceneform ARcore example

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I think this might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360658/gray-lines-instead-of-camera-feed-in-arcore-app-builds) post but posting here with a screeenshot (and in hopes for increased visibility).

When loading hellosceneform example to a Galaxy S9 camera feed displays garbled grey and black stripes with AR field visible in the background.

[Hello sceneform output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq46N.jpg)

Thanks for any assistance and please crosspost any answers to Sean Krist! :)

Comment: This is a known issue with the S9.  Please watch https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/28 for updates.

Comment: Thanks Clayton! I also ended up discovering the sample worked fine running natively.